# HTML href dynamic syntax

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, href

I want to add the variable change.number generated dynamically to href hyperlink

```
<td><a href="abc.com/Change/Request/"><c:out value="${change.Number}"/></a></td>
```

What should be my modified syntax in order to add change.number to hyperlink .

Comment: <td><a href="abc.com/Change/Request/"><c:out value="${change.Number}"/></a></td>

Comment: YOu can try with this - <td><a href="abc.com/Change/Request/${change.Number}">Use a text</a></td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<td><a href="abc.com/Change/Request/${change.Number}"><c:out value="${change.Number}"/></a></td>
```